# Silverlight client does not get copied on to the Silverlight Web project clientBin folder

Tags: silverlight

Hi When trying to run the Build Locally Silverlight client files does not get copied on to the  Silverlight web's ClientBin folder, any idea what to do? The Version of Silverlight is 3.0

Answer (score 0):

More information needed.  you can first go to you web site property to check if you set the silverlight application path to clientbin folder.

Comment: Yes it does, What I mean is when I created the Silverlight Application from Visual Studio, it created 2 projects, SilverLight client and Web Project, when I just run this project I get error, now I copy the files from the Silverlight Client Application Bin directory and copy it to Silverlight Web Project's ClientBin folder and I am doing this manually everytime I make change to client project, I want to avoid it, I know there should be some issue to MSBuild Task for this, But I dont know what to fix and where to fix.

Thanks in Advance,
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the properties of the web application.
2. There is a group called "Silverlight Application"
3. Click the Add button
4. Select "Use an exisiting Silverlight project in the solution" and select the Silverlight project from the drop down.
5. Make sure that the Destination folder field is set to ClientBin.